# Decoupled architecture approach with dynamic web project eclipse

Tags: java, jquery, eclipse, maven, tomcat

The `eclipse-maven-tomcat` project(containing `html/css, jquery, javascript`) will make ajax-jquery calls, using exposed web service url's(using json/xml) and interact with database. The database persistence layer and web framework (`spring`), etc, modules are part of another project which exposes web services.

Will using the above mentioned [technologies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41933499/create-a-website-with-eclipse-maven-tomcat) will follow the headless websites/[decoupled architecture](https://pantheon.io/blog/headless-websites-whats-big-deal-decoupled-architecture)?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [this answer](https://www.quora.com/What-is-headless-architecture):

> A "Headless Architecture" is a buzz phrase in the software development community pertaining generally to web applications describing an approach which splits the code base cleanly between server side (e.g. REST webs services) code which defines data and business logic from client side (e.g. JavaScript) code which invokes the logic and renders the data and typically as part of an MVC pattern.

So *of course* you can implement this using HTML/CSS/JS for the front-end and Spring for backend in separate projects.

Eclipse, Tomcat or Maven are quite orthogonal to the question.